# How to add code and html markup to another VS solution file without having access to it or subversion

Tags: visual-studio-2008

A company hired me to add some functionality to a pre existing .NET site, the problem is I have to create it in my own VS solution file and somehow integrate it into the existing site without access to the original VS solution file.  The pre existing site is not in subversion.  I coded up some stuff that works on my end, but they can't add it to the application with out getting some sort of server error.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can't they send you the existing code source? It's like asking someone fixing your car without giving him the car.

Comment: No, apparently not. it's with the hosting company who developed the site initially and this company I'm working for doesn't seem to see the importance of me working from the original solution.

Comment: Truly one of the more bizarre client requests I've heard of... "can you fix our application without the code?"

Answer (score 0):

Is the functionality such that they could create a virtual directory under their site, and put your work in that?

Beyond that...what's the server error they're getting?

Comment: I have tried to talk them into something like that, but they don't seem to understand why they cant just upload the new code to the server...I don't know what the error is specifically, but it breaks the app.  I don't see how this will work at all.